# Excel VBA HTML IDs

Tags: html, excel, vba, forms

I am working on a VBA script based upon:  [Source Example](https://www.encodedna.com/excel/web-scrapping-fill-a-web-form-from-excel-using-vba.htm) to fill in a web form from excel.

I get a VBA 91 error and i think the issue is i am not fully qualifying the HTML ID.  The code as found by inspecting the form in a browser looks like this:

```html
 <input type="text" 
 title="Identification" 
 id="ComboBoxField_TS0003" 
 group-id="TS1" 
 data-link-id="2TS" 
 data-box-id="73" 

originalwidth="5" 
class="k-combobox  leftalign  TS1" 
allowcustomtext="False" 
mandatory="true" 
name="ComboBoxField_TS0003" 
maxlength="3" 
style="height: 20px; width: 60px; position: absolute; left: 360px; top: 82px; display: none;" 
value="AB1" 
data-role="combobox" 
aria-disabled="false" 
aria-readonly="false" 
haskeydown="true" 
hasclick="true">
```

Just to get the basics right before i start filling in forms and advancing through a some rows of data, i modified the encodedna example as follows:

```
Option Explicit
Const sSiteName = "http://domain/LIVE/ui/web/home?Function=TS&Parameter1=A&Source=Client"


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim oIE As Object
    Dim oHDoc As HTMLDocument
    
    Set oIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
    
    ' Open Internet Explorer Browser and keep it visible.
    With oIE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate sSiteName
    End With
    
    While oIE.ReadyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend
 
    Set oHDoc = oIE.Document
    
    With oHDoc
        .getElementById("ComboBoxField_TS0003").Value = "ZX9"

' group-id="TS1" data-link-id="2TS" data-box-id="73"
        
        .getElementById("bt").Click
    End With
End Sub
```

So i think i need all 4 IDs in order to send a "value" i want entered in the form.

If thats correct, how do i go about multiple qualifying IDs?  Most examples only have one ID.

Comment: I do not believe that the multiple ID types are your issue. I have a feeling that your webpage is not fully loaded prior to you trying to enter the ZX9 value.  Have you tried stepping through the code line-by-line using F8 and verifying the page is fully loaded prior to entering the value?  I don't like the readystate<> 4 code you use, I would try replacing it with `Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop` which has been more successful for me in the past.

Comment: If the form is loaded dynamically then in addition to do a loop checking for `readystate`, you might even need to do another loop to check for an element that you know exist but will be loaded later before proceeding to fill up the form.